# Azure release pipeline curl script failure

Tags: curl, azure-devops

I have a curl command under bash script of Azure release pipeline.

```
curl -u admin:password -F file=@"_My_App_Maven_CI\drop\app-content-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip" -F name="pp-content"    -F force=true -F install=true http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/crx/packmgr/service.jsp
```

I have verified that artifact has been published under drop folder in build pipeline (My_App_Maven_CI\drop\app-content-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip)

I am getting an error with release deployment failure.

```
curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application
2023-04-13T03:43:17.3149393Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '26'.
```